Updating PivotCache on one tab to loop through and update pivots on another in Excel
I have a file with two tabs, "data" and "pivots". The data is updated daily and so the range of the pivot cache is not static.  Various pivots get updated from the data.  I tried to write the below in order to create a macro that will update the pivot cache and then run a loop to update each pivot:
Sub UpdatePivots ()

'Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare dimensions
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTC As PivotCache
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range

'Update the pivot cache
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WSD = WB.Worksheets("Data")
Set Rng = WSD.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set PTC = WB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Rng, Version:=8)

'Use loop to cycle through pivots and update with new cache
For Each WS in WB.Worksheets
    For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
         PT.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next PT
Next WS

'Turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Currently I am not interested in making the data tab a table.  I also added a MsgBox after setting the Rng as well as after the loop and always see that the active sheet is "pivots".  So, I am obviously missing the way to actually update the cache which would be on "data".
I have tried to change the parameters of the PTC code, but get errors because I don't know what I am doing :)

Format your data in Structured Tables (Select your data including column headings and press Crtl+t, make sure that "My Table has headers" is checked adn press OK). Now use the Structured Tables as your Datasources for your Pivots.  As you add/remove data, the Structured Tables automatically resize and your Pivots have the correct data all the time.

Can you comment as to why the written code does not work?

.CurrentRegion is not always reliable.  Excel likes to hang on to old formatting and .CurrentRegion can grab that old formatting and consider it part of it.  Structured tables as your Source would eliminate the need for setting your Source altogether. Simply update your data and because your source is the Table (which flexes in size based on the data), you no longer need to update your Source.

Thank you for clarification on .CurrentRegion.  For the solution you are offering, when you change the data source to a table, you no longer need to write any VBA for the update correct,  It would just be refreshing the Data tab in the workbook?

Correct.  Update your data and refresh your Pivot and you're done.  Using the VBA you've written is literally doing something that Excel does natively.  It's kind of like writing a function to do a Copy/Paste.  Use the KISS method whenever possible...

From strictly the standpoint of getting the original code above to work by combining a number of pieces of other threads together, the below updated code appears to work:
Sub UpdatePivots ()
    
    'Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Declare dimensions
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim WSD As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PTC As PivotCache
    Dim RngStart As Range
    Dim SlctData As Range
    Dim NmdRng As String

    'Update the pivot cache
    Set WSD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set RngStart = WSD.Range("A1")
    Set SlctData = WSD.Range(RngStart, RngStart.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    NmdRng = WSD.Name & "!" & SlctData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    Set PTC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
       SourceData:=NmdRng, Version:=8)
    
    'Use loop to cycle through pivots and update with new cache
    For Each WS in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            If PTC.Index Then
                PT.CacheIndex = PTC.Index
            Else
                PT.ChangePivotCache PTC
            End IF
       Next PT
    Next WS

    'Refresh the cache
    PTC.Refresh
    
    'Turn on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub

Changes from the original: removed declaring the workbook dimension, dropped .CurrentRegion for new Dim Ranges (RngStart and SlctData) to select the data in the space and then convert this to a string (NmdRng) for subbing into the pivot cache.  I don't know why the index worked for me and not the for loop that I saw on other threads, but this worked.
